# Graphs satisfying Moore Bound for irregular graphs

Tags: graph-theory

For graphs where all vertices $\textbf{except one}$ have degree $d$ and one vertex has degree $< d$ and girth at least $g$, is there a lower bound on number of vertices (similar to Moore bound for regular graphs)?

If so and if it is achievable, could you give an example graph meeting the bound?

Thanks in advance!